# Rotate objects in a specific Axis and Stop

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am not the author of this question, but it was only made in this [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138242/rotacionar-objetos-em-torno-do-eixo-especifico-css) in the Portuguese Stackoverflow by Eryc Masselli, and I am really interested in an answer for this since I found it really intriguing. I will translate it below:

> I would like to know how to rotate and object (div) around an axis of
>   another object (another div). My problem is the following: I have a
>   big circle and 5 other small circles under the big one. Each circle is
>   a separate div.
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> What I need is that when one of the small 5 circles is clicked, it
>   rotates in a clockwise, around the big circle, manner until it takes
>   the third circles's position. The following is an example of the
>   rotation after the circle of number 4 is clicked:
>
> [image: The circles will move until the clicked circle takes the position 3]
>   **Subtitle:** *The circles will move until the clicked circle takes the position 3*
>
> I need this to be done **ONLY** with CSS, but in case it is
>   impossible, the solution may use j if it is not too much. Thank you!

Well. I believe this is no simple task only with CSS, so I am willing to take any answer as long it is something doable. Thank you for the help!

Comment: for a single animation css could help http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rybOmw , but for interaction you will need javascript, CSS will require lots of rules and extra markup to trick it and will break easily

Comment: @GCyrillus The original OP asked for a only CSS answer, but as I said, I am open to more elaborate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said, this a javascript job ;)

CSS will need lots of extra HTML markup and redundant CSS rules (SASS or similar would help but why not plain js ?)

here is an average  example using a couple of rules copied/paste many times.

```css
.circle {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 25vh auto;
  position: relative;
}

.rotate {
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10vh;
  margin-left: -5vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.rotate div {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #0095FF;
}
#a, #a div , #b , #b div , #c, #c div, #d, #d div, #e, #e div {transition:1s;}
#a,  #b ,  #c,  #d, #e {transform-origin: 5vh 0;}
#a{z-index:1;}
label{cursor:pointer}
/* one */

#one:checked ~ .circle  #a {transform: rotate(120deg);}
#one:checked ~ .circle #a  div {transform: rotate(-120deg);}

#one:checked ~ .circle #b {transform: rotate(90deg);}
#one:checked ~ .circle #b div {transform: rotate(-90deg);}

#one:checked ~ .circle #c {transform: rotate(60deg);}
#one:checked ~ .circle #c div {transform: rotate(-60deg);}

#one:checked ~ .circle #d {transform: rotate(30deg);}
#one:checked ~ .circle #d div {transform: rotate(-30deg);}

#one:checked ~ .circle #e {transform: rotate(0deg);}
#one:checked ~ .circle #e div {transform: rotate(-0deg);}

/* two */

#two:checked ~ .circle  #b {transform: rotate(120deg);}
#two:checked ~ .circle #b  div {transform: rotate(-120deg);}

#two:checked ~ .circle #c {transform: rotate(90deg);}
#two:checked ~ .circle #c div {transform: rotate(-90deg);}

#two:checked ~ .circle #d {transform: rotate(60deg);}
#two:checked ~ .circle #d div {transform: rotate(-60deg);}

#two:checked ~ .circle #e {transform: rotate(30deg);}
#two:checked ~ .circle #e div {transform: rotate(-30deg);}

#two:checked ~ .circle #a {transform: rotate(360deg);}
#two:checked ~ .circle #a div {transform: rotate(-0deg);}

/* three */

#three:checked ~ .circle #c {transform: rotate(120deg);}
#three:checked ~ .circle #c  div {transform: rotate(-120deg);}

#three:checked ~ .circle #d {transform: rotate(90deg);}
#three:checked ~ .circle #d div {transform: rotate(-90deg);}

#three:checked ~ .circle #e {transform: rotate(60deg);}
#three:checked ~ .circle #e div {transform: rotate(-60deg);}

#three:checked ~ .circle #a {transform: rotate(390deg);}
#three:checked ~ .circle #a div {transform: rotate(-30deg);}

#three:checked ~ .circle #b {transform: rotate(360deg);}
#three:checked ~ .circle #b div {transform: rotate(-0deg);}

/* four */

#four:checked ~ .circle #d {transform: rotate(120deg);}
#four:checked ~ .circle #d  div {transform: rotate(-120deg);}

#four:checked ~ .circle #e {transform: rotate(90deg);}
#four:checked ~ .circle #e div {transform: rotate(-90deg);}

#four:checked ~ .circle #a {transform: rotate(420deg);}
#four:checked ~ .circle #a div {transform: rotate(-60deg);}

#four:checked ~ .circle #b {transform: rotate(390deg);}
#four:checked ~ .circle #b div {transform: rotate(-30deg);}

#four:checked ~ .circle #c {transform: rotate(360deg);}
#four:checked ~ .circle #c div {transform: rotate(-0deg);}

/* five */

#five:checked ~ .circle #e {transform: rotate(120deg);}
#five:checked ~ .circle #e  div {transform: rotate(-120deg);}

#five:checked ~ .circle #a {transform: rotate(450deg);}
#five:checked ~ .circle #a div {transform: rotate(-90deg);}

#five:checked ~ .circle #b {transform: rotate(420deg);}
#five:checked ~ .circle #b div {transform: rotate(-60deg);}

#five:checked ~ .circle #c {transform: rotate(390deg);}
#five:checked ~ .circle #c div {transform: rotate(-30deg);}

#five:checked ~ .circle #d {transform: rotate(360deg);}
#five:checked ~ .circle #d div {transform: rotate(-0deg);}

input[name="group"]{position:absolute;right:100vw}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="radio"  name="group" />
<input id="two" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="three" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="four" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="five" type="radio" name="group" />
<div class="circle">
  <div id="a" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="one">1</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="two">2</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="three">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="four">4</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="e" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="five">5</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That is very similar to what I wanted. I will tweak it a little bit and see what else a can try.

Comment: I was able to tweak your CSS and got something very similar to what was asked! Thank you very much for your help! I want to give you the "Accepted Answer", but I wish to post the tweaked version as an answer.

Comment: @LeonFreire great ! i see the same problem, it goes round always on the same direction, no matter the initial position of the clicked element. But if it did not matter , its fine ;)

Comment: Actually I wanted it to always go Clockwise. Sometimes I still see it going Counter-Clockwise depending of the position. What I did manage to fix with the tweaking was to put them on the desired position when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for @GCyrillus for the help. I was able to tweak his answer and get what I really needed. The code is below:

```css
.circle {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 25vh auto;
  position: relative;
}

.rotate {
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10vh;
  margin-left: -5vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.rotate div {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #0095FF;
}

#a,
#a div,
#b,
#b div,
#c,
#c div,
#d,
#d div,
#e,
#e div {
  transition: 1s;
}

#a,
#b,
#c,
#d,
#e {
  transform-origin: 5vh 0;
}

#a {
  z-index: 1;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}


/* one */

#one:checked~.circle #a {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #a div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #b {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #b div {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #c {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #c div {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #d {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #d div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #e {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#one:checked~.circle #e div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


/* two */

#two:checked~.circle #b {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #b div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #c {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #c div {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #d {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #d div {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #e {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #e div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #a {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#two:checked~.circle #a div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


/* three */

#three:checked~.circle #c {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #c div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #d {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #d div {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #e {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #e div {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #a {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #a div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #b {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#three:checked~.circle #b div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


/* four */

#four:checked~.circle #d {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #d div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #e {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #e div {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #a {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #a div {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #b {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #b div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #c {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#four:checked~.circle #c div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}


/* five */

#five:checked~.circle #e {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #e div {
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #a {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #a div {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #b {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #b div {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #c {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #c div {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #d {
  transform: rotate(390deg);
}

#five:checked~.circle #d div {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

input[name="group"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100vw
}
```

```html
<input id="one" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="two" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="three" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="four" type="radio" name="group" />
<input id="five" type="radio" name="group" />
<div class="circle">
  <div id="a" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="one">1</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="two">2</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="three">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="d" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="four">4</label></div>
  </div>
  <div id="e" class="rotate">
    <div><label for="five">5</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```